# JQuery AJAX Refresh Div on Interval and Change Content on Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a backend control panel with a "modal" dialog box that I would like to use to display live information (job progress, server information etc.).  What I need is for a certain div (the dialogue box) to "refresh" (grab html content from another php page) on a regular interval (1 second), but also depending on which button I pressed to display the dialog box, it would refresh from a different php page.

Here is the code for the dialog box:

```
<!-- Modal dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                One fine body&hellip;
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And any button can display it using:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Modal dialog</a>
```

I found this code that seems to let me update the modal content from a php page (that I will dynamically create, that I know how to do): [how to use jquery or ajax to refresh a div at 10 second intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865102/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-refresh-a-div-at-10-second-intervals)

However I assume I need a javascript onClick to change the url in the javascript function, depending on which button I press?  I would imagine breaking the javascript into two separate functions, one to set the url (move to a global variable) and one to start the refresh interval, however I am new to javascript and want to see if this is the right method to use before I delve into coding it.  I've never used an onClick even before.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Hello you would have something like that for the interval part:

http://jsfiddle.net/35Lyzbjc/

Something like that:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = t;

    // you would normally put here the $.get of your PHP page
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```