# How to refresh a page from other page from anywhere

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, signalr

I have hosted 2 website and I have to refresh 1st site whenever I press a refresh button from 2nd site it must refresh everywhere wherever 1st website is loaded. I have tried using flag pointer storing in db, Ajax post but not working as required.
The first website will be loaded in a device and 2nd website will be loaded in users device. when user clicks refresh button it must reload the 2nd website.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not just in words. Do add your script here in question.

Comment: `it must refresh everywhere wherever in.html is loaded` - so any browser, any client, everywhere in the whole of the WWW that currently has `in.html` must be updated whenever any browser, everywhere in the whole of the WWW does a refresh on index.html? Is that what you need?

Comment: no wait ... anywhere in the whole of the WWW, where `in.html` is loaded, `index.html` must be reloaded (what if index.html isn't loaded?), whenever index.html is refreshed anywhere? chances are, without very careful code, a single refresh could cascade into an avalanche of refresh requests unless you differentiate between a user initiated refresh and an external differentiated refresh ... are you writing "yet another chat application" by chance?

Comment: I just want to refresh a page when user from userside who loads index.html and clicks refresh button passes the command to a device which will be loaded with in.html will refresh onclick of user. The name of file is just for example.

Comment: i think you must try some thing to refresh page/section (not whole page, required section only) by a time interval and make updates on `in.html` page. That would be better. like https://stackoverflow.com/a/6398590/4229270, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865181/4229270,

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use websockets.[socket.io](https://socket.io).

Here is how your flow should be your 2nd website will call an API of your server. On receiving request from your 2nd website you will fire a socket which will broadcast to all the peers (in this case all the 1st website instances what are currently loaded on the browser). On receiving these sockets 1st website will fire **Location.reload()** command and reload the its own state.

Answer (score 0):

please which technology you use ?
i've seen that long polling isn't convenient for you thus see websocket
technology.
If you use nodejs i recommend you to use socket.io https://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

You could use socket.io and have it so the server will talk to the other website